# Après l'école, c'est moi qui m'occupe de mes frères

Tags: sens, verbes-pronominaux

I am not sure how you would be able to translate this phrase. I think it's trying to say that I take care of myself and my brothers but how am I meant to figure that out?

First of all, the clause 'c'est moi qui m'occupe' translates to 'it is me who occupies myself', so how can you follow this phrase on with 'de mes frères'.
Can someone please sort out my confusion?

Any answers would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You have to identify ***je m'occupe de*** as the **reflexive** form of a verb.

You seem to have got so far as to identify you are dealing with a reflexive verb but the problem might be that in English the verb you need is **not** reflexive.

And you might be missing that in order to look it up in a bilingual dictionary the ***de*** is necessary. So you have to look up for ***s'occuper de***.  And [that's](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-occuper-de) what you find:

> s’occuper de
>   [club] to be in charge of
>   ; [affaire, question à régler] to deal with
>   ; [malade, invité] to look after
>   ; [clients] to serve
>   ; [politique] to be involved in

From those you should be able to deduce which one is relevant for your sentence.

As you progress you will find that French has a lot of reflexive verbs that are not reflexive in English. And you will need to know some of them quite early as you learn. For instance *s'appeler* (I'm called)/my name is..), *se lever* (stand up/get up), *s'habiller* (get dressed), *se fâcher* (get angry), *s'ennuyer* (get bored)... Indeed a lot of French reflexive verbs will end up in English as "get+past participle or adjective", but you cannot hold it as a rule. And of course sometimes the *se* and be identified as an action upon yourself like *se couper* (to cut oneself).

Comment: How do you feel about *c'est moi qui m'en occupe* vs *c'est moi qui s'en occupe* = *celui qui s'en occupe, c'est moi*?

Comment: @Minty "c'est moi qui s'en occupe" is not possible. ***Celui qui** s'en occupe, c'est moi* implies that the person you are talking to knows of the possible choice of people, *c'est moi qui m'en occupe* is more neutral.

Comment: I wondered about that, thanks - it just seems strange that any normal English speaker says *it's me who lookS after...*, whereas French speakers say *c'est moi qui M'en occupe...*.

Answer (score 1):

"S'occuper" and "s'occuper de qqc ou qqn" are two different verbs; so you can't have "occupies myself" and it must be "who is taking care of".

The meaning is then "After school, I'm the one taking care of my brothers." or put in a more usual way "After shool, it is me who takes care of my brothers.".

PS Always check a good dictionary, such as for instance the TLFi; that could provide those clues to you already and in any case it would start teaching you how to read it and progress in the way of extracting much information from it yourself.

Comment: Recommending the TLF to a beginner in French is the last thing I would do (unless I want to discourage them). You already need a solid background in French to be able to use it.

Comment: @Laure I don't believe so; the sooner you start the better: you've just got to keep picking at it. I remember the days when you started studying English in the first year of college in France, the reason  being that the children in primary school weren't yet mature enough; this is not the modern point of view; nowadays they can start studying English in kindergartens: Depuis la rentrée 2018, quinze écoles maternelles et primaires du département de l'Essonne (91), ont mis en place (champ 1)

Comment: @Laure le programme européen Emile dans 95 classes des villes d'Orsay, de Massy Palaiseau ou d'Evry, de Courcouronnes ou Gif-Sur-Yvette. Ce programme, qui date des années 1990, veut permettre un meilleur apprentissage des langues étrangères via un enseignement bilingue. »  See for instance this source from which comes the extract: https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/le-reportage-de-la-redaction/lecole-en-anglais-des-le-primaire .

Comment: You are entirely beside the point. Using the TLF has got nothing to do with bilingual learning.  Of course  we'd need to agree about what "bilingual" means but this is not the place to discuss and I'm sure from what you say we wouldn't. All I will allow myself to say (from experience) is that so called *classes bilingues/bilangues* hare absolutely not "bilingual" it is only a commercial name (I do not restrict "commercial" to making money).

Comment: @Laure The point is the difficulty involved; what this lowering of the age means is that the task can be started much earlier; it's the same thing with a dictionary: it is not necessary to know all there is to know about its presentation and all the abreviations to read some parts of it and to understand them; little by little, discovery after discovery you get to know the dictionary and the language better. A very good way to learn is by doing.

Comment: @LPH I agree with your last point. But I also agree with Laure that the TLFi can be discouraging, even for weathered native French users. I think it best to start small and build upon. The Wiktionary, with its more synthetic (hum...) and user-friendly interface, could be a good start before moving to something more elaborate. Same as in any domain: don't start running by trying to achieve a marathon; begin with running ten minutes, build your strength and do more.

Comment: As for the fact of beginning earlier: the brains of children are more malleable, they learn more easily than grown-ups. Better to plant the seed early, as children who learned the fundamentals of both languages early will have less difficulty growing fluent in both.

Comment: @Chop The argument here is **not** about early beginnings (provided you **don't call bilingual**, bilingualism is something completely different and what LPH was pointing has nothing to do with it, the word is used promotionally and not in as scientists do). The argument is about recommending a complete beginner using the TLF (a dictionary even some natives have difficulties understanding).

Comment: @Laure I use the TLFi myself and I had a question about it some time back on the FSE that has still not been answered properly; however, this dictionary remains the one I use mainly:  there is available in it a scope that is not available elsewhere and which is accessible to a lot of people; you'll find in it a solution to your questions often whereas other dictionaries, less comprehensive, less concerned with grammar, simply leave you without means. I am not recommending not to use along with it a simple dictionary, but  that one should start acquainting themselves early with it.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Encore une fois vous sautez aux conclusions sans aucun argument de réfutation ; tout au contraire, il n'y a aucun radotage. Le point à considérer c'est le degré de maturité nécessaire pour aborder certains sujets; il y a une analogie réelle et elle est tout simplement que comme dans le domaine d'un sujet compliqué tel que l'anglais l'étude et l'exploitation d'un dictionnaire n'ont pas à être pris par le bout le plus difficile et dans leur entièreté avant de pouvoir commencer à en tirer profit et à permettre de mieux les connaitre ;  (champ 1)

Comment: @suiiurisesse de la même manière que l'âge jugé celui de la maturité idéale pour l'anglais a été considérablement abaissé on ne peut pas logiquement avoir pour l'étude d'un dictionnaire une approche différente. Quant à vos idées d'attraction culturelle et de bilinguisme elle sont complètement hors sujet. Votre dénigration de ce dictionnaire est biaisée par je ne sais quoi ; c'est le premier dictionnaire recommandé par les plus hautes autorités en matière d'étude du français aux États Unis, cela n'est pas un hasard. (champ 2)

Comment: @suiiurisesse  La masse de la langue française est loin d'avoir été changée en 25 années et de plus une bonne partie de ce qui aura été introduit dans ces 25 années n'a aucun avenir assuré dans le langage, en particulier lorsque son effet est de déplacer ou de pervertir des notions acquises dont le but du dictionnaire est en partie de préserver ces notions contre des influences inconsidérées, souvent le produit de l'utilisateur ignorant et inéduqué dans l'esprit de la langue, cet utilisateur qui empile sans savoir ce qui se trouve au fond de la pile. (fin)

Comment: @suiiurisesse Je pense moi-même que ce dictionnaire n'est pas parfait; il ne doit y en avoir aucun de parfait; il serait souhaitable qu'un système de mise à jour permanente soit établi. Encore une fois, je conçois bien un dictionnaire comme un  rempart, certes, mais je ne prétend pas que seul un dictionnaire soit la solution ni qu'une solution soit parfaite. Passons pour la futilité, je peux ne pas la voir, me tromper, mais il n'y à rien de prétentieux dans l'idée d'une langue de synthèse même si personne n'a encore mis beaucoup d'espoir dans l'Esperanto. Il y a du monde qui le connait.

Comment: Bof, peut-être qu'un moment donné je finirai par comprendre ton dessein de synthèse de la langue. Ce n'est pas encore le cas. L'exclusion systématique de tout ce qui n'est pas normatif ou soigné ne permet pas d'obtenir un portrait juste de la langue et de sa richesse à mon avis.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Du point de vue strict de dépendre pour une communication complète d'une langue artificielle il n'est plus question d'amputer quoi que ce soit et en quelque sorte de se priver de rejetons de valeur, ce n'est plus un problème : tout est spécifié aux normes, tout est soigné, simplifié et économique au maximum par définition. Le grand problème, et c'est celui-là même que l'on perçoit dans votre souci "de portrait juste", non pas de la langue mais de la vie, de l'existence, est  de concevoir ce système évolutif tel qu'il puisse intégrer rapidement des  (champ 1)

Comment: @suiiurisesse formulations pour les  besoins d'expression de groupes suffisamment importants (des groupes d'intérêt) et moins importants comme les auteurs pris individuellement. C'est une affaire de science linguistique et de politique dans laquelle on est amené à reconsidérer ce qui constitue l'art de l'expression et dont la perspective laisse perplexe en raison d'un certain inconnu qui s'ouvre à nous. Je ne vois pas non plus de voie toute tracée pour mettre en train une telle entreprise; je n'ai pas du tout l'idée préconçue que ce soit vraiment possible ou facile; (champ 2)

Comment: @suiiurisesse cependant, par exemple, il me semble d'emblée que le personnel actuel dédié à l'entretient du langage et qui serait converti à de nouvelles tâches serait, malgré les besoins important d'un nouvel appareil d'administration, réduit de beaucoup. Ce que je maintiens néanmoins c'est que, si cette possibilité était envisageable, c'est à dire qu'elle puisse être réalisée en préservant ce qu'il y a de bon dans le système actuel, (champ 3)

Comment: @suiiurisesse on mettrait fin au chaos indéniable qui règne dans le domaine de la langue. Je dois dire finalement que ces considérations qui sont les miennes montrent que l'on ne peut pas parler justement de « mon dessein » mais au plus d'une vision. (fin)